# Python Prime Number Loop

Tags: python, primes

I am having difficulty ending the loop. I have tried break,continue, and pass. The program needs to be able to read non-integer numbers and repeat the line of code, until it is satisfied. I can't break the loop.

```
prime_num = input('Please enter an integer >= 2: ')

while not(prime_num.isdigit() and int(prime_num)<1):
    input('Please enter an integer >= 2: ')
for i in range(2,int(prime_num)+1):
    for x in range(2,i):
       if i%x == 0:
           break    
       else:            
           print (i)
```

Comment: You'll need to go through and fix the indentation. I did my best but since whitespace is meaning in python, you'll need to make sure I got it right.

Answer (score 1):

Prime Number is not defined the second time you ask the end user for the integer.
try

```
def prime_number():
    prime_num = input('Please enter an integer >= 2: ')
    while not(prime_num.isdigit() and int(prime_num)<1):
        prime_num = input('Please enter an integer >= 2: ')

    for i in range(2,int(prime_num)+1):
        for x in range(2,i):
            if i%x == 0:
                break
        else:
            print (i)
```

Is that what your looking for?

Answer (score 0):

When you're asking for input a second time...

```
while not(prime_num.isdigit() and int(prime_num)<1):
    input('Please enter an integer >= 2: ')
```

... you're not assigning the result back to `prime_num`, so the condition will never be satisfied.

Instead of duplicating the `input()` line, a different approach would make more sense:

```
while True:
    prime_num = input('Please enter an integer >= 2: ')
    if prime_num.isdigit() and int(prime_num)>1:
        break
# etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Break is working fine in Python. It breaks the inner of your two loops. There is, however, no break for breaking more than one loop.

The main issue with your code is a problem with your algorithm. A number gets printed by your code as a prime number for **each** number >=2 by which it can not be divided. So for example you get printed once "15" (or any other non-even number) because it can not be divided by "2".

Your algorithm must make sure that a number is only printed as a prime number if **all** the divisions you test have failed.